# Configuring Single Sign-On Across Stratos

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos, wso2-identity-server

I have a situation where I need to setup a standalone version of wso2 Identity Server and have that act as the SSO provider into all of the products in Stratos.

Currently I have Stratos Identity Server configured so that I can login via the standalone Identity Server, using admin.

However, if I use another user I either

1. get a "Authorization Failure"
2. or cannot login.

**First Question**

1) I have the same user created in both Identity Server (that is not admin). Why would I get the "Authorization Failure" ?

**Second Question**

2) Why is it I can not even get to the "Authorization Failure" problem if I have a user created with username in format of user@domain.com ?

UPDATE:

I figured out that if I remove the property tags in user-mgt.xml that reference the usernames with regular expressions I am able to create usernames in the format of name@domain.com.  But I am still unable to use that username to login, the error log says that the account has not been activated.

I also created two instances of wso2 identity server and configured them in such a way to test being able to use one to login to the other. I was able to do this by making sure that the same username and password was in both servers list of users.  This way I do not get the "Authorization Failure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers I came up with.

1. I need to have the same username and password in each Identity Server.

2. I cannot have format name@domain.com unless I have Multi-tenancy configured. Otherwise wso2 will try to find the ACTIVATE field in the Tenant table and not find it.

UPDATE: I got this installed and configured and it turned out that I now get another error about

```
Issuer details are not valid. Issuer details should be registered in advance
```

So my answer turned out not to to be valid.

```
I wonder why I get this new login failure?
```

UPDATE RESOLVED!!:

I resolved this problem by downloading just the wso2 stratos IS 1.5.2 package. I installed it. Configured with same configuration I was using before. Now I can login without problems across domains.

Comment: WSO2 Stratos 1.6.0 is available for you to download at http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos. It is a pre-configured pack and SSO is also configured and works fine.